# Ionic 2 Accordion is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, accordion, ionic3

I'm trying to create Accordion using below code. But I'm getting error.

But If I comment subCategory(below) html code I'm not seeing issue.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.ProductSubCategory" *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_Id)">{{subCategory.Description}}</a>
      </ion-item>
```

HTML Accordion:

```
  <ion-list *ngIf="categories.length > 0">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index" text-wrap (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">
      <h3>{{category.Description}}</h3>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.ProductSubCategory" *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_Id)">{{subCategory.Description}}</a>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Component:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public service: Service) {

    this.loading.present();
    this.service.getCategoryData(this.id).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.service.getCategories()
                .then(result => {
                    this.categories = result;
                    this.loading.dismiss();
                });
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
}


toggleGroup(group) {
    if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
        this.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
        this.shownGroup = group;
    }
};
isGroupShown(group) {
    return this.shownGroup === group;
};
```

**ERROR:**
 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("ory.Description}}

```
      <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.ProductSubCategory" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">

        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@100:76 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
```

Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("ory.Description}}

```
      <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.ProductSubCategory" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">

        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@100:76
at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1540)
at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12031)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:25782)
at compiler.es5.js:25706
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:25706)
at createResult (compiler.es5.js:25591)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3 Error: Template parse errors:
```

Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("ory.Description}}

```
      <ion-item *ngFor="let subCategory of category.ProductSubCategory" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">

        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@100:76
at syntaxError (http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:85381:34)
at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:95872:19)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:109623:39)
at http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:109547:62
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:109547:19)
at createResult (http://localhost:4400/build/vendor.js:109432:19)
at t.invoke (http://localhost:4400/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
at r.run (http://localhost:4400/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
at http://localhost:4400/build/polyfills.js:3:13731
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `*ngfor` and `*ngIf` in the same element. Instead, you can use the *ng-template sintax* like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<ng-template ngFor let-subCategory [ngForOf]="category.ProductSubCategory">
    <ion-item *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
        <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_Id)">{{subCategory.Description}}</a>
    </ion-item>
</ng-template>
<!-- ... -->
```

The `ng-template` element won't be rendered, is just to include the logic related to the `*ngFor`.

You can find more information in **[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)**

Comment: <ion-template ngFor let-subCategory [ngForOf]="category.ProductSubCategory">
            <ion-item *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
              <a (click)="callProductDetails(subCategory.Product_SubCategory_Id)">{{subCategory.Description}}</a>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-template>

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
"let-" is only supported on template elements. ("
          <h3>{{category.Description}}</h3>

          <ion-template ngFor [ERROR ->]let-subCategory [ngForOf]="category.ProductSubCategory">

            <ion-item *ngIf="isGroupShown(i"): ng:///AppModule/HomePage.html@100:30
'ion-template' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-template' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-template' is a Web Component then add  of this component to suppress this message. ("<h3>{{category.Description}}</h3>